Populate a value automatically based on the current value of another attribute using a QGIS form
I have two tables: tableA with two attributes (city names and cityID). In tableB, I have several attributes, including the same attributes as in tableA. In tableB, when I add a new entity and fill in cityname, I'd like cityID to be filled in automatically, even when I change cityname later.
Under layer properties and then attribute form oftableA, I chose to use relational values as follows:  layer = tableA, key column = cityID, value column = cityname.
For tableB I chose: layer = tableA, key column = cityID, value column = cityID.
As default value of tableB, I tried following expression without success. I don't know the right approach to use.
CASE
WHEN  'cityname' =   get_feature('tableA', 'cityname') THEN  'cityID' = get_feature('tableA',  'cityID'  ) 
END

What expression should I use to get the desired result?
I use QGIS 3.34.

There's several fundamental problems with your understanding of expressions. I've explained what the errors are systematically below, but I strongly recommend you also read through the explanatory text and examples for each function when constructing it in Expression Builder, and take a closer look at examples from related posts on GIS.SE.

Firstly, you need to use double quotes, not single quotes, when referring to fields from the current layer.
Single quotes will just return the actual static text value cityname, instead of returning the value in the feature (e.g. Atlanta, Lansing, etc.) You only use single quotes to refer to fields if it's from another layer in the functions get_feature() and attribute().
e.g.,
CASE WHEN "cityname"                   --this is from your layer

= get_feature('tableA', 'cityname'...) --this is from the other layer

THEN "cityid" ...                      --this is from your layer


Secondly, get_feature() is not used properly.
Again, have a closer read of the explanatory text and examples for get_feature() in the Expression Builder window. You need to extract the feature from the other layer (like a VLOOKUP in Excel) in three steps:

specify the other layer by name (single quotes)
specify the field in the other layer by name (single quotes)
compare the value of the field in your current layer (double quotes), to search in #2 above. If there is a match, return the first match.

So in your case this would be
get_feature('tableA',    --name of the other layer
            'cityname',  --name of the other layer's field to look up
            "cityname")  --value of this layer's field


Thirdly, get_feature() alone will return an entire feature from another layer. This is the entire collection of fields and values and cannot be directly compared to the output of a field ("cityname").
Instead, you need to use attribute() to extract the actual value from the feature to make the direct comparison.
In your case this would be (pay attention to the quotation marks)
"cityname" = attribute(get_feature('tableA',     --whole feature
                      'cityname',
                      "cityname"),
          'cityname')               --attribute to extract from whole feature


Finally, you need to think of a CASE statement as a result of a logical condition. Not a function that can independently assign values to fields. You just have a result.
WHEN is the logical condition (which must return true or false).
THEN is the result. What is the result of "cityid" = X? There is an = in there which makes that also a logical condition. Either cityid is equal to X (true), or is not (false). So if you use this as your default value expression, your result, which will be placed in your fields, would be true or false (1 or 0). Not the actual value from the other layer.
If you want to just get X as a result, this is what the syntax should look like:
CASE
WHEN (condition...) 
THEN X
ELSE (other result...)
END


Combining all the above with some simplification, your expression should look like the one below. This can be simplified further to avoid doing the lookup twice but for now this makes the logic very clear and easy to follow.
CASE

WHEN get_feature('tableA',               --condition: test if you can find a feature in tableA with a matching cityname value
                 'cityname',
                 "cityname")

THEN attribute(get_feature('tableA',     --result: get matching feature from tableA...
                           'cityname',
                           "cityname"),
               'cityid')                 --...and extract the cityid value
ELSE
'insert text'                            --catch-all for when there is no matching cityname in tableA
END


Note the ELSE value won't be relevant if you use a Value Relation widget for the field in tableB, as it can only return values that exist in the specified layer and field. You could use a Value Relation widget for the cityname field in tableB, and Text Edit widget for cityid.
